# Some questions on coherent states and corresponding Hilbert spaces. Reproducing kernal

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, eigenvalue, coherent-states

I have a few questions related to coherent states. I use this source
https://homepage.univie.ac.at/reinhold.bertlmann/pdfs/T2_Skript_Ch_5.pdf.

Using standart inner product $\langle\cdot|\cdot\rangle$ in Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ we can find the value of coherent states and Fock states at a point, if I understand correctly, as shown in $(5.126)-(5.128)$ by the link above. But directly calculating, I get a different result 
$$\langle x|m\rangle=\exp^{-|x|^2/2}\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n!}}\,\langle n|m\rangle=\exp^{-|x|^2/2}\frac{x^m}{\sqrt{m!}}.$$ Where am I mistaken? This is the first question.

It is also interesting to me, Is the set of coherent states dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$? Or maybe it forms some Hilbert subspace? Is it possible to build a reproducing kernal in it?

Comment: You should consult the canonical textbook by Perelomov on coherent states for your questions.

Comment: Note that (126) and (127) are NOT coherent states, but  the standard h.o. wavefunctions in the position representation.

Comment: This book?
"Generalized coherent states and some of their applications
A M Perelomov"

Comment: That is, it is not a inner product between the coherent state and wavefunction in 126-127?